# Using data from Observable Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

First, I'd like to thank the community for all the support learners like me get while working with new technologies.
I've been using Angular for a while now, and there's something I still don't quite understand nor have I seen asked elsewhere.

Supposing I have a service that returns an Observable with the data I need, how should I use this data properly, in terms of performance?

1. I know I can use the async pipe and avoid having to sub/unsub, but this only happens in the template. What if I needed to use the same data in the component as well? Wouldn't subscribing again (from the template with the async pipe and from the component with .subscribe())?
2. How do I keep the observable up to date? For example, I have a table displaying data from an API. If I click on the 2nd page (pagination), I'd like to make another call and have the observable updated.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I personally couldn't find if on Stackoverflow. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: that's why Observable's operators are for : combinating observables...

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Is there any example you could give for any of these cases?

Comment: I'm working on it, please, be patient...

Comment: Oh sure, sorry! Thank you

Comment: this post will help you to understand a lot http://blog.angular-university.io/functional-reactive-programming-for-angular-2-developers-rxjs-and-observables/

Comment: Thank you, @MarianoMontañezUreta, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need the data in the component as well, you can just subscribe to it. **BUT** maybe you should not (see below)...
2. it's there that you use the operators, you can combine observables to define a custom data flow:

```js
foo$: Observable < Foo[] > ;
randomClickEvent = new Subject < clickEvent > ();

ngOnInit() {
    let initialFetch = this.fooService.getData().share()
    this.foo$ = Observable.merge(
      initialFetch, // need the initial data
      initialFetch.flatMap(foos => { 
        this.randomClickEvent.switchMap(() => { //listen to click events
          return this.fooService.getMore().map((moreFoos: Foo[]) => { //load more foos
            return foos.concat(...moreFoos) //initial foos values + new ones
          })
        })
      })
    );
  }
```

```html
<span *ngFor="let foo of (foo$|async)">{{foo.name}}</span>
<button (click)="randomClickEvent.next($event)">Load More foos !</button>
```

Most of people just use simple operators like `map()`,`do()`, etc and manage their subscription imperatively, but it is usually better to not subscribe, so you avoid many side effects and some "Ooops I forgot to unsubscribe here". usually you can do everything you need without subscribing.

Observables exist to describe a data flow, nothing more, nothing less. It's a paradigm of functional programming: you don't define how things are done, but what they are. Here, `this.foo$` is a combination of the initial `fooService.getData()` and every `fooService.fetchMore()` that may occur.

Comment: Very interesting... I thought subscribing again to the Observable would be a kind of waste of resources, but looks like this is the way to go...
I'll try this approach to refetch the values.
Thank you very much for your reply!!